# Weird rendering of bounding box

Tags: c++, marmalade

I'm trying to make a bounding rect for my bullet which is in space invader game. 
I'm using marmalade, and the bounding rect seems translated and doesn't bound the bullet at all, however the math is correct. 
Here is a video of the behavior and a snippet of code
http://youtu.be/SbjMPKQ7ilE

```
void Bullet::Render()
{
    if (ShipBullet == nullptr)
        return;

    if (Visible)
    {
        Transform.SetIdentity();

        // Build transform
        Transform.SetRot(Angle);
        Transform.ScaleRot(Scale);
        Transform.SetTrans(Position);
        Iw2DSetTransformMatrix(Transform);
        Iw2DSetColour(Colour);

        CIwFVec2 pos = Transform.t;
        BoundingRect.x = pos.x;
        BoundingRect.y = pos.y;
        BoundingRect.w = (float)ShipBullet->GetWidth();
        BoundingRect.h = (float)ShipBullet->GetHeight();

        // Render image
        if (ShipBullet != 0)
        {
            int x = -(ShipBullet->GetWidth() / 2);
            int y = -(ShipBullet->GetHeight() / 2);
            Iw2DDrawImage(ShipBullet, CIwFVec2(x, y), CIwFVec2(ShipBullet->GetWidth(), ShipBullet->GetHeight()));
        }

// render bounding rect 
#if 1
        Iw2DSetColour(0xff0000ff); // Set red
        Iw2DDrawRect(CIwFVec2(BoundingRect.x, BoundingRect.y),
            CIwFVec2(ShipBullet->GetWidth(),ShipBullet->GetHeight()));
#endif 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the same coordinates for both of your objects.

```
void Bullet::Render()
{
    if (ShipBullet == nullptr)
        return;

    if (Visible)
    {
        Transform.SetIdentity();

        // Build transform
        Transform.SetRot(Angle);
        Transform.ScaleRot(Scale);
        Transform.SetTrans(Position);
        Iw2DSetTransformMatrix(Transform); // Set a 2D transform to apply to all 
                                           // subsequent drawing operations. This 
                                           // is taken into considration for the 
                                           // Iw2DDrawImage and Iw2DDrawRect calls, 
                                           // bellow. 
        Iw2DSetColour(Colour);

        CIwFVec2 pos = Transform.t;
        BoundingRect.x = pos.x;
        BoundingRect.y = pos.y;
        BoundingRect.w = (float)ShipBullet->GetWidth();
        BoundingRect.h = (float)ShipBullet->GetHeight();
        // I don't know where but the BoundingRect must be used somewhere else. 

        // You have already applied the transformation with the position of your 
        // object, which you consider as being the center. You now have to offset 
        // the graphics by its size to draw it around the center. 
        int x = -(ShipBullet->GetWidth() / 2);
        int y = -(ShipBullet->GetHeight() / 2);

        // Draw the image, x/y is top left, per the documentation (http://api.madewithmarmalade.com/group__iw2dImages.html#ga60855d305af26248dd9eb71fcb4c656d)
        Iw2DDrawImage(ShipBullet, 
            CIwFVec2(x, y), 
            CIwFVec2(ShipBullet->GetWidth(), ShipBullet->GetHeight()));

// render bounding rect 
#if 1
        Iw2DSetColour(0xff0000ff); // Set red
        Iw2DDrawRect(
            CIwFVec2(x, y),
            CIwFVec2(ShipBullet->GetWidth(),ShipBullet->GetHeight()));
#endif 

    }
}
```

From what I understand from marmalade, a call to Iw2DSetTransformMatrix(Transform) sets the transformation for all your subsequent calls. Then you have to use the same data if you want to have both your objects at the same location.

Edit:

See my comments in the code, and more explanation:

You could have used the x/y of the Position and of the BoundingBox *if* you did not use the position in the calculation of the Transform (and the subsequent call to Iw2DSetTransformMatrix). By using the x/y of the bounding box, you were actually moving your bounding box twice: one because of the position/call-to-Iw2DSetTransformMatrix, and once because you were offsetting it by it's position again.